# PowerShell Windows Registry loop won't end

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get this loop to work as I need it to check if a program installed, however it only works if the display version is already `21.1.21.45`. If it doesn't exist or it changes when the exe is is installed the loop won't break.

```
$Variable1 = [Version](Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{AA3C5F33-570B-3989-8542-D5DC0F759221}').DisplayVersion 

do {
  Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
} until ({$Variable1 -eq [Version] "22.1.30.45"})
```

Comment: `$Variable1` is assigned a value, once, before you start looping. It's never updated inside the loop.

Comment: can i have an example please as I am new to powershell, and the only reason I am learning it because of intune

Comment: Use a foreach : foreach($variable in variable1)

Comment: Change `until ({$Variable1 -eq [Version] "22.1.30.45"})` to `until ($Variable1 -eq [Version] "22.1.30.45")`

Answer (score 0):

here is the answer

```
[Version]$minVersion = "21.1.21.45";
do {
  $version = [Version]'0.0.0.0'; try { [Version]$version = [Version](Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{AA3C5F33-570B-3989-8542-D5DC0F759221}' -EA 0).DisplayVersion; } catch { }
  if ($version -ge $minVersion) {
  #Write-Host "The version is now '$($version)', which is greater than the Minimum version '$($minVersion)'";
  }
  else {
  #Write-Host "The version is now '$($version)', which is less than the Minimum version '$($minVersion)'. Will wait 15secs.";
  Start-Sleep -Seconds 15;
  }
}
until($version -ge $minVersion);
```